# How to handle Content-Description:File Transfer in AngularJS $http response

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

**Short version:** $http request works fine on desktop, fails on mobile

Within an Angular controller, I have a $http GET call to a resource which returns the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Description:File Transfer
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=verses.json
Content-Length:1392
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
Date:Sun, 16 Aug 2015 23:13:18 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:public
Server:Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.16
```

As you can see in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sortofbusy/utb5mfn4/3/), the response is recognized as JSON.

**However,** if you load the same JSFiddle on a mobile device nothing returns. I've looked into $http's transformResponse, but the documentation is pretty sparse and I can't find an example of someone trying to get what I'm getting. There are examples of turning a JSON response into a downloadable file, but I'm looking for the opposite.

I know the obvious solution is to ask the API to return application/json instead of application/octet-stream, but until that happens, I'd appreciate any help or just pointing me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I'd start with removing non-sense header fields (headers that do not have any meaning in HTTP), such as "Content-Description" and "Content-Transfer-Encoding". Do the same for all caching related information for now.